# taskVarAdd used twice for the same variable

Tags: vxworks

I have a global struct added to my task using taskVarAdd() API.

But during some scenarios, the same global struct is is added to the same task again using taskVarAdd() API. [i.e., taskVarAdd() is called twice from a task for a same variable].

This struct will maintain the taskID, message queue ids for that task.

### My Questions:

1. If we call the taskVarAdd() for the same variable twice inside a task, what will be the behavior?
2. Whether the struct variable added first will be overwritten by the second variable?{I feel this will be overwritten]

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to do a simple test case.

`int v1;
void tvl()
{
   v1 = 1;
   taskVarAdd(0, &v1);
   v1 = 2;
   taskVarAdd(0, &v1);
   v1 = 3;
   taskDelay(1);
   printf("Initial v1 = %d\n", v1);
   for(;;)
   {
     v1++;
     taskDelay(60);
     printf("v1 = %d\n", v1);

   }
}`

Running the test code results in the following values for v1:

```
Initial v1 = 2
1 3 3 2 4 4 3 5 5 4...
```

The same code with a single taskVarAdd gives the expected result of 1 2 3 4 ...

PS: You didn't specify the version of VxWorks, so what I said is valid for Vxworks 6.x

Comment: Hi Benoit,

Thanks For your response. Currently we are using VxWorks 5.5

Kindly explain your program? I am not able to understnad the behavior clearly.

I have tested your code using tornado and i am getting different results every time i execute your program

//1st Attempt
-> tv1
Inital v1 = V1 = 3
V1 = 3
V1 = 2
V1 = 4
V1 = 4
V1 = 3
V1 = 5
V1 = 5
V1 = 5
V1 = 6

//2nd attempt
-> tv1
Inital v1 = V1 = 1
V1 = 3
V1 = 4
V1 = 2
V1 = 4
V1 = 5
V1 = 3
V1 = 5
V1 = 6
V1 = 4